# Changing PmWiki user profiles links?

Tags: php, pmwiki

I have an existing website with its own user-management which I am incorporating [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/) into.

I am therefore using the [ExternAuth](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/ExternAuth) recipe in PmWiki to handle my authentication. This works fine, allowing me to authenticate users based on session variables set by my existing user authentication system.

However, there is a single shortcoming: PmWiki will on several pages make links to user profile pages. E.g. when showing who edited pages. 
I would like these links to instead of pointing to non-existing Wiki-pages of the form `Profiles/UserName` to point back to my existing user profile pages.

Is there a way to change the way the PmWiki `[[~UserName]]` links are rendered on the page to an "external" link like `http://example.com/profiles/UserName` instead of the normal PmWiki behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out for myself... The trick was to use the Markup command to define a markup that would change user-profile links at the same time as other "inline" markup to an external link. This link will then later in the markup-chain be converted to a real HTML link which will point externally.

```
// Set author information:
$AuthId = $_SESSION['userid'];
$Author = $_SESSION['name'] . ' (userid=' . $_SESSION['userid'] . ')';

// Change the way links to user profiles are shown:
$EnableAuthorSignature = 1; // Allow for ~~~ and ~~~~ markup
$AuthorLink = "[[http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/profiles/{$_SESSION['userid']} | {$_SESSION['name']}]]";
Markup("profilelinks", "inline", "/\[\[~(.*?)\s\(userid=(\d+)\)\]\]/", "[[http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/profiles/$2 | $1]]");
```

I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution, but it seems to work...

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `http://` you might want to make the protocol a capture group, in case your website moves over to SSH (`https://`). Glad you could figure this out!

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis `https://` isn't SSH. Also, `"$UrlScheme://"` works.

Answer (score 0):

The original author link `[[~user]]` is define in `script/author.php` as:

```
Markup('[[~','<links','/\\[\\[~(.*?)\\]\\]/',"[[$AuthorGroup/$1]]");
```

where `$AuthorGroup` is set by default to the "Profiles" group name.

You may change it to your needs with:

```
DisableMarkup('[[~');
Markup('[[~','<links', '/\\[\\[~(.*?)\\]\\]/',"[[($UrlScheme://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/profiles/)$1]]");
```